# TYPO3 10.4.21 - Update extension list

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Centos 7, PHP 7.2.24, TYPO3 version 10.4.21

I want to update the list of TYPO3 extensions but I encounter the following error

> Error: Update Extension List Could not access remote resource
> https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.

Do you have a solution please?

Comment: Please check if your OpenSSL library is up to date. See also https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/ and https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/

Comment: Additionally to what Simon wrote you can try to use curl from the command line of your webserver to test if not for example a firewall is blocking your request: `curl -I https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz`. This should return `HTTP/2 200`.

Comment: First, thank you for your answers.
**1 - I would like to know how check if mi OpenSSL library is up to date or not ?**
**2 - curl -I https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz show** 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx 

thank you.